# python paho mqtt run client for x minutes

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I want to run my paho mqtt client for specified period of time and not forever. What is the right way to implement it?

P.S. I want a blocking call and not the event driven loop_start()/stop() facility

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the event loop or it just won't work.

So your best bet is to implement your own loop and keep track of time. e.g.

```
startTime = time.time()
runTime = 5 * 60
while True:
  mqttc.loop()
  currentTime = time.time()
  if (currentTime - startTime) > runTime:
    break
```

This should run for 5 mins